# Connect two PCs using LAN cable over ipv6

Tags: lan, home-networking, ipv6

I have to transfer the data from 1 pc to another using LAN cable. I know how to do it with ipv4, but I have some problem while using ipv6.

Steps I have done:

1. Dis-select the ipv4 opting from network settings, in both PCs.
2. Connect both pc with a LAN cable.
3. Set the following on PC1:  ipv6 adddress : fdc0::0001  offset length: 64   default Gateway : fdc0::0003
4. Set the following on PC2:  ipv6 adddress : fdc0::0003  offset length: 64  default Gateway : fdc0::0001

Now, I am able to ping PC1 from PC2 and vice versa, but not able to do the data transfer.

*note: I have shared some folders on both PCs to everyone with full access rights.

Comment: Use the Ipv6 address with your Adapter %AdapterNumber you can get this by `netsh interface ipv6 show interface` then use your IPV6Address%AdapterNumber.ipv6-literal.net and you should be able to access the other pc.

Comment: NetworkKingPin: that is only necessary for link local addresses. With ULA and global unicast addresses that only complicates things.

Comment: In this setup you don't have a default gateway. Both machines pointing at each other as default gateway will cause a loop for all packets whose destination isn't one of the machines. Like DNS queries for example. You should leave the default gateway empty on both sides. You don't have a gateway and you don't need one to communicate on a LAN.

Comment: Another possible source of problems in this case might be things liked firewalling etc. I assume you turned those off :)

Comment: @SanderSteffann yes the firewall is off on both the machine, and will try with empty gateway value.
Are the IPs correct which I am using?

Comment: You are using IPv6 addresses from the ULA range. Officially you have to generate a semi-unique prefix, but in your case it should be fine for now. If you continue you should generate a prefix on e.g. http://unique-local-ipv6.com to use

Comment: @SanderSteffann I am not able to ping the ip address which I am using but able to access the files though, what can be the possible reason for the same. Firewall is off on both machines. – Nitesh 23 hours ago